# Grid View Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net

Fist off, I'm very new to **ASP.NET** and **Visual Web Developer Express**.

I have a datagrid that I want to display subtotals in and have grouping.

I found this http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm which looks great. I've added the classes files to my projects App_code folder and re-built the project.

I have the code working great!!  except when I want to edit a field in the data grid view it doesn't want to write back to the sql database.  When I take this code out it works fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: Could we see the code that you are using to do edits/updates? It would probably help to see your HTML/aspx `<asp:datagrid ...>` definition.